# Creating a transparent selector for button and shape

Tags: android

I tried to create a selector for my button, using the the following XML codes...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:constantSize="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rectangular_transparent" android:state_enabled="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rectangular_grey" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
</selector>
```

this is the rectangular gray shape I have defined...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/grey"/>
    <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

and this is the rectangular transparent shape I have  defined...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <stroke android:color="@color/grey" android:width="@dimen/_1sdp"/>
    <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

When I run it into my device, it shows only transparent button but it doesn't change color when i press...

The same approach works when I try to use with other color than transparent, please help...

Comment: if you look closely both colors aren't transparent, I used transparent stroke for solid grey fill and grey stroke for  solid transparent fill...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of items in a selector is important. It always picks the first one that applies. So you should swap those items.

In your case, the button is always enabled, no matter what pressed state is, so it always picks the first item.

Comment: I'm new here, this is literally my first post :) 
Accepted your ans, thank you once again :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use selector in right way :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:constantSize="true">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rectangular_transparent" ></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rectangular_grey" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
```

**or**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:constantSize="true">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rectangular_transparent" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rectangular_grey"></item>
```

Comment: Use edited answer . and put stroke width in your shape drawables.